# Why my pagination won't work fine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

I have 3 models such as User, Community, and Uniquecode.
Then I'm using `kaminari` for pagination.

I'm facing the problem, in which the number of uniquecode records varie(change) at each params[:page].

In addition, `<% @uniquecode_count %>` returns '1'... It has to be '1', though.

This is really weird.  In my case. I had 3 Uniquecodes.
As I did put `paginates_per 1` in Uniquecode model, it should show only 1 record at each page. However

- At Page. 1  It shows 3 records
- At Page. 2  It shows 2 records
- At Page. 3  It shows 1 record

Can anyone help me to solve this?

I defined association like this

```
User has_many :communities
User has_many :uniquecodes

Community belongs_to :user
Community has_many :uniquecodes

Uniquecode belongs_to :user
Uniquecode belongs_to :community
```

**uniquecode model**

```
paginates_per 1
```

**controller**

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@uniquecodes = @user.uniquecodes.page(params[:page])
@uniquecodes_count = @uniquecodes.count
```

**view**

```
<%= paginate @uniquecodes, :window => 4 %>
<% @uniquecodes.recent.each do |uniquecode| %>   
    <%= render 'uniquecodes/uniquecode', :uniquecode => uniquecode %>
<% end %>

<% @uniquecode_count %>  => this shows '1'. It has to show '3' though.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PER_PAGE = 1 # declared as class constant
@uniquecodes = @user.uniquecodes.page(params[:page], :per_page => PER_PAGE)
```

pass per_page

Comment: I did `no_of_records = 1`, but it's still the same result:(

Comment: Or defined as class constant PER_PAGE = 1 and used as
@uniquecodes = @user.uniquecodes.page(params[:page], :per_page => PER_PAGE)

Comment: I made it `no_of_records = 1`

Comment: Can you guess why this is messed up?